# Any "null" strings in the CSV file should be replaced with the SQL value null in pyspark dataframe - Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am having a Dataframe which has "null" as strings and i wanted to replace it with SQL value null in PySpark Dataframe in Databricks.

Could someone please help with that. I am relatively new to Spark.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df = df.withColumn('string_col' , expr("CASE WHEN col = 'null' THEN NULL else col END")
```

Basically you're replacing the bad strings with NULL value, otherwise leaving original value. Replace the 'string_col' & 'col' with proper names.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import when
>>> data = (['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['null', 3])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['str', 'id'])
>>> df.show()
+----+---+
| str| id|
+----+---+
|   A|  1|
|   B|  2|
|null|  3|
+----+---+

>>> df.withColumn("new_col", when(df.str == "null", None).otherwise(df.str)).show()
+----+---+-------+
| str| id|new_col|
+----+---+-------+
|   A|  1|      A|
|   B|  2|      B|
|null|  3|   null|
+----+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Also extending from @Hegde's answer above, I simply tried with `.replace()` api of Pyspark (also works with Databricks), it works like below :

`newDF = DF.replace("null", None)`

Resultingly, the `newDF` would finally contain a SQL NULL in all places where "null" (as a string) was present.

*Some tip :
In order **to replace any missing/blank strings with SQL NULL in dataframe**, then try as :
`.replace("", None)`
i.e. passing an empty pair-of-quotes in exchange for the `None` (or, `null`) values.*

Happy Coding!